# How to get the text from a input field then set it as a placeholder for a different input field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am making a `form` builder. I would like for the user to be able to set the the placeholder text of an `input` field by typing what they would like it to be in a different `input` field.

So far I have tried this:

HTML:

```
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="Title" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>Placeholder</label>
            <input type="text" id="PlaceHolder" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" onclick="Confirm()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function Confirm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Title");
    var y = document.getElementById("PlaceHolder");
    x.setAttribute("placeholder", y.innerText);
    console.log(x.innerText);
    }
```

However, the placeholder value for the first input field doesn't change and the `console.log` returns an empty space.

Comment: You have to use `value` and not `innerText` of the `input`.

Comment: use x.setAttribute("placeholder", y.value); instead of x.setAttribute("placeholder", y.innerText);

Comment: Thanks im a bit annoyed as when i typed in my question to ask it, The question that it is a duplicate of didnt come up but i found out the answer now anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code: You switched `x` and `y` - and you need to use `value` instead of `innerText`

```js
function Confirm() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Title");
  var y = document.getElementById("PlaceHolder");
  y.setAttribute("placeholder", x.value);
}
```

```html
<label>Title</label>
<input type="text" id="Title" class="form-control" placeholder="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <label>Placeholder</label>
        <input type="text" id="PlaceHolder" class="form-control form-control-sm">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button type="button" onclick="Confirm()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</div>
```